# Proving $((A \to B) \to B) \to B$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 154, exercise D. 7). It is the last exercise of Chapter 16. This is what I got so far.

Is my $IP$ strategy correct ?

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{
 \fitch{¬(((A \to B) \to B) \to B)}{
   \fitch{¬((A \to B) \to B) }{
     \fitch{¬(A \to B)}{
       \fitch{B}{
         \fitch{A}{
           B
          } \\
          A \to B \\
          \bot
        }
      }
    }
  }
}$

P.S: Here is a link to the open-source book:
[forallX](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf)

Comment: I couldn't locate this exercise in the downloadable version of the book. It would be more helpful to give a chapter and section reference, because the page references may vary in different formats of the book.

Comment: Ok, I’ll edit my question to include the information you suggest.

Comment: I think you need to give a URL. The online version of the book I can find only doesn't have a chapter 16.

Comment: Maybe what they intended the exercise to be is Peirce's law: $((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$.

Comment: @RobArthan, just added a link as a P.S.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. You have misquoted the proposition to be proved. As Daniel conjectured you are being asked to prove Peirce's law.

Comment: @RobArthan In my edition, it is as I wrote it. Being open source, perhaps it was recently corrected.

Comment: My commiserations to you on having to work from an unstable text.

Comment: I just found two or three typos. Other than that, the book is simply awesome.

Comment: As far as I see, the exercise D.7 in Ch. 16 of the book you mentioned ask for a proof in natural deduction of the formula $((A \to B) \to A) \to A$ (aka Pierce law), not of the formula $((A \to B) \to B) \to B$ you mentioned in the title.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, as I said to Rob, they probably changed it in a recent update. It was as I wrote it when I downloaded the book (probably one month ago).

Answer (score 4):

Use a truth table.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & A \to B & (A \to B) \to B & ((A \to B) \to B) \to B\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Since the last column is not identically true (i.e., "$1$"), then you can conclude that $ ((A \to B) \to B) \to B$ is not a tautology.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(A \to B) \to B$ is logically equivalent to $A \lor B$. So $((A \to B) \to B) \to B$ is logically equivalent to  $(A \lor B) \to B$, which is **not** a tautology: if $A$ is true and $B$ is false, $(A \lor B) \to B$ is false.